# $location.path does not change the route after form submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have seen many issues regarding the $location.path in angular js on stackoverflow but none of them would solve the issue I have.

I have defined below routes in my app.js:

```
angular.module(
    'hotPosts',
    [ 'hotPosts.filters', 'hotPosts.services',
            'hotPosts.directives',
            'hotPosts.controllers', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize' ]).config(
    [ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/hot-posts', {
            templateUrl : 'gptarin/partials/hot-posts.jsp',
            controller : 'ListPostsCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/list-users', {
            templateUrl : 'gptarin/partials/list-users.jsp',
            controller : 'ListUserCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/edit-user/:userId', {
            templateUrl : 'gptarin/partials/edit-user.jsp',
            controller : 'EditUserCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/create-user', {
            templateUrl : 'gptarin/partials/edit-user.jsp',
            controller : 'EditUserCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/hot-posts'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

    } ]);
```

The list-users.jsp partial will show a list of users where I can select a record to update. When I click ong update button the ngRoute successfully routes the app to edit-user.jsp partial. However, when I click the Save button in that page, it does not change the route to "/list-users", even though I used the `$location.path('/list-users')` in Controller EditUserCtrl. It redirects me to "[app_url]/?".

Here is my controllers:

```
app.controller('EditUserCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$routeParams',
    'UserListFactory',
    'UserFactory',
    '$location',
    function($scope, $routeParams, UserListFactory, UserFactory,
            $location) {

        // callback for ng-click 'updateUser':
        // force it to refresh in the client
        $scope.saveUser = function() {
            if (angular.isUndefinedOrNull($scope.user)) {
                $scope.user = {};
                UserListFactory.create($scope.user, function() {
                    $location.path('/list-users');
                });
            } else if (angular.isUndefinedOrNull($scope.user.id)) {
                UserListFactory.create($scope.user, function() {
                    $location.path('/list-users');
                });
            } else {
                UserFactory.update($scope.user, function() {
                    $location.path('/list-users');
                });

            }
        };

        // callback for ng-click 'cancel':
        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $location.path('/list-users');
        };

        if ($routeParams.userId !== undefined) {
            $scope.user = UserFactory.show({
                userId : $routeParams.userId
            });
        }

    } ]);
```

The update function (`saveUser`) uses a service which makes Restful requests to the backend server via ngResource. The service works fine (all tests are passed).

I have enclosed the $location.path in the success callback function when calling the resource actions.

I have tried catching `"$locationChangeSuccess"` and `"$locationChangeError"` and saw that in this case a `$locationChangeError` is thrown but I do not know which promise object is rejected causing this error.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here is the edit-user.jsp partial

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title label">Edit User</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form role="form" action="#" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="saveUser()">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-11">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="accountId" class="col-sm-1 control-label">G+
                            Id: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" id="accountId" class="form-control"
                                ng-model="user.gpId"></input>
                        </div>
                        <label for="accountName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" id="accountName" class="form-control"
                                ng-model="user.name"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="showPosts" class="form-control"
                                ng-model="user.listPosts">ShowPosts</input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-12 pull-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-12 pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well After a few days of trying everything and not finding any help over internet I sort of fixed this issue.

I decided to share it with whoever reads this post so that it does not take several days of them as well.

When I traced my app more carefully I figured out that my cancel button worked just fine and `$location.path` was successfully sending me back to the `/list-users` page.

Further investigations showed that the difference between my Cancel and Save buttons was that the Cancel button uses the `ng-click` whereas I defined the type of my Save button to be "submit".

I then changed my html code so that instead of providing the function call `saveUser()` in `ng-submit` of the form, I used an `ng-click` for the Save button and changed its type to "button".

Here is the working version of my html partial. I did not need to change anything in js files.

```
<form role="form" action="#" class="form-horizontal">
    <!--  ng-submit="saveUser()"> -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm-11">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="accountId" class="col-sm-1 control-label">G+ Id: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" id="accountId" class="form-control" ng-model="user.gpId"></input>
            </div>
            <label for="accountName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" id="accountName" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <label> 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="showPosts" ng-model="user.listPosts"> Show Posts
                </label> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveUser()">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I still still do not now the mechanics of form submit in angular and why it causes one of the promise objects that the $location.path expects to fail (and hence causing an error in routing).

Any clarifying comment in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. had the same issue. strange strange strange ;)

Comment: Hi I have the same situation but this time not the form, is a page say **details?id=1** and I got a function such that it checks if the user is logged in `if not logged in ?` I need to send the user to **/signin** page, but as you experienced, the url is **signin?id=1** , here I cannot apply ng-click. So am a bit stuckup.

Comment: well I found a solution to get rid of **?id=1**. It was a bit simple `$location.url(''); $location.path('/signin');` did the work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well after more than a year of experience with Angular, I now know what was the problem in the first instance.
Reading Angular's documentation for ng-submit I found out this:

Additionally it prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but only if the form **does not contain action**, data-action, or x-action attributes.

Looking at the code it is evident that I mistakenly added an **action** attribute when I was defining the form element:

```
<form role="form" action="#" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="saveUser()">
```

Removing it will fix the problem:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="saveUser()">
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add  $event.preventDefault(); before saveUser(); it will works.